# Why do the lights near the wall in my media room have a separate switch?

Tags: lighting

This is the media room in a house I recently bought:

[image: picture]

The lights along the wall on the right, indicated by red arrows in the picture, have a separate light switch. The lights are directed down, not at the wall. Why are they controlled separately? Is it to light the aisle, if a TV were installed in the stone area in the center of the picture and seats placed in front of it?

Comment: Because soneone wanted them that way. We can't read their mind, but one possibility would be "aisle lighting" when the room is otherwise darkened, and another might be additional lighting for a work area, and....

Comment: Where was the TV when you viewed the property?

Comment: @Grim There was none.

Comment: Could be to illuminate works of art.

Answer (score 1):

- There may have been plans for a desk/workspace there
- There may have been plans for a bar or cabinetry/countertop there
- There may have been plans for a display shelf there
- There may have been plans for ...

If you can procure the original design drawings it's probably mentioned what the plan was.